# Laravel: Resource Controller change parameter from ID to Slug

Tags: laravel, parameters, controller, resources

In my Laravel application I was using the normal routes, such as GET, POST, PUT and all with the various controllers. But as the application progresses, the `routes/api.php` file is turning out quite bulky. So, I am changing it with the "Resource Controller" syntax, for cleaner and reduced code.

However, earlier I was able to use the "token" or "slug" parameters in the url to fetch the data, for example: *show/{token} & show($token)* or *show/{slug} & show($slug)*, but now whenever I try these or any other parameter I get `404 not found` error. Therefore I am stuck with the default "id" parameter only.

**Earlier:**

```
Route::get('/categories', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/categories/{token}', 'CategoryController@show');
```

**Now:**

```
Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoryController');
```

Is there any way to change the default "id" parameter to any other ..?

Comment: You mean you want to change what's laravel pick as primary key field?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because I don't want to show the Id of the record to everyone. It may turn out to be a security issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Resource Routing the route parameter is the resource name, first argument, in singular form.

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
```

Will give you a route parameter of `category`. You can see this by running `php artisan route:list` and looking at the routes that are defined.

If you want to use a different parameter name for a resource you can also do that by overriding the parameter:

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController')->parameters([
    'categories' => 'something',
]);
```

Now the route parameter used would be `something`.

This only has to do with the route parameter name, it has nothing to do with how any binding would be resolved, unless you had an Explicit Route Model Binding defined specifically for a parameter name.

If you are using Implicit Route Model Bindings you would define on your Model itself what field is used for the binding via the `getRouteKeyName` method. [In the next version of Laravel you will be able to define the field used in the route definition itself.]

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Controllers - Resource Controllers - Naming Resource Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Routing - Model Bindings - Implicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding) `getRouteKeyName`

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, the `getRouteKeyName` did the work for me. :)

Answer (score 14):

This can also be achieved by changing the [customizing the key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping). In here `slug` refers to a column in the Category model.

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController')->parameters([
    'categories' => 'category:slug',
]);
```

**Please note**:

In the call to `parameters` above, the key `categories` should match the name used in the resource route: `Route::resource('categories',...`.

The value, `'category:slug'`, should match the name used in the method signature of the controller, eg: `public function edit(Category $category)`, combined with the name of the key you wish to use on the `Category` model.

Comment: This worked, just a little explanation. for implicit model binding, the parameter should be same to the model name(singular) in most cases. 
In the example above it will be `->parameters([
    'categories' => 'category:slug',
])`
That is if you want to bind the model using `slug` instead of `id`, where the `{category:slug}` will replace the URI segment `{category}`. You cal always run `php artisan route:list` to check the URI segment