# Dependency Injection not working with parameter change

Tags: php, laravel

I am unable to understand why below is not working, I have defined my route like below

```php
Route::apiResource('/api/support-staffs', SupportStaffController::class);
```

If I perform a `route:list` I get

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                | Name                   | Action                                                           | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/support-staffs                 | support-staffs.index   | Custom\SupportStaff\Controllers\SupportStaffController@index   | auth:api
   |
|        |           |                                    |                        |                                                                  | bindings
   |
|        | POST      | api/support-staffs                 | support-staffs.store   | Custom\SupportStaff\Controllers\SupportStaffController@store   | auth:api
   |
|        |           |                                    |                        |                                                                  | bindings
   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/support-staffs/{support_staff} | support-staffs.show    | Custom\SupportStaff\Controllers\SupportStaffController@show    | auth:api
   |
|        |           |                                    |                        |                                                                  | bindings
   |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/support-staffs/{support_staff} | support-staffs.update  | Custom\SupportStaff\Controllers\SupportStaffController@update  | auth:api
   |
|        |           |                                    |                        |                                                                  | bindings
   |
|        | DELETE    | api/support-staffs/{support_staff} | support-staffs.destroy | Custom\SupportStaff\Controllers\SupportStaffController@destroy | auth:api
   |
|        |           |                                    |                        |                                                                  | bindings
   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

My `supportStaff` happen to be users so I am trying to perform a dependency injection like below

```
  public function show(User $user)
  {
    return $user;
  }
```

And changing my route to

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'bindings'])->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('/api/support-staffs', SupportStaffController::class)
      ->parameters(['support_staff' => 'user']);
});
```

Unfortunately I am receiving back an empty `[]` array. Why isn't `support_staff` parameter being replaced with the `user` parameter? I have confirmed by running `route:list` that the parameter is still  `support_staff`

Comment: did you try it with `User $support_staff` in your show method? does it work?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59137762/2324206

Comment: @Haridarshan I have gone through the question but its different from my current issue

Comment: @SumitWadhwa $support_staff  works fine,