# Is there a way to prevent Laravel from removing the ending "s" from a parameter name in a route?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to setup Laravel as a REST Api but I've encountered a default Laravel behavior that I would like to work around.

In my api.php, I'm defining default routes for a model named "Pays" (French for country), like so:

```php
Route::resource('pays', PaysController::class);
```

Problem is, I end up with routes like these:

```
GET|HEAD  | api/pays/{pay} | pays.show   | App\Http\Controllers\PaysController@show   | api
PUT|PATCH | api/pays/{pay} | pays.update | App\Http\Controllers\PaysController@update | api
```

I was wondering if there's any way to tell Laravel *not* to remove this ending "s" ? I could probably modify the argument's name in the Controller, but I would rather not do that just out of common sense.

Comment: The attribute name is not visible in your URL so thats no problem. It would be better to code in english in Laravel. A lot of functionality is converting plural to singular (for example db table users and model user).

Comment: You could still add all routes manually. Here are the [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59137762/8292439) work? You should be able to change the parameter name, although I'm not sure if Laravel would still strip the last `s`.

Comment: @Gert B. I usually code in English but our teacher specifically asked us to use French for this project, a soft spot of his...

Comment: @brombeer True, true, but I was hoping for a "lazier", less verbose way :)